# how to safely send hidden variables of paypal form?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I have a paypal form which will have hidden variables i can change the amount using firebug to edit it. how to avoid this before send this form to paypal i am not storing any values in my db. should i store these datas in db once got success value from paypal should i check with current amount equals to sent amount item id.

```
<form id="paypal_form_one_time" target="_top" class="paypal-form" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">

    <input type="hidden" value="110.00" name="amount"> 

    <input type="hidden" value="xxxx@xxx.com" name="business">
    <input type="hidden" value="12345" name="item_number">

    <input type="hidden" value="Featured for 3 Months ($99)" name="item_name">

    <input type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_note">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_shipping">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="rm">                   
    <input type="hidden" value="feature_item_id=1&amp;deal_item_id=0" name="custom">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://localhost/xxxx/xxxx/paypal_success" name="return">

    <input type="hidden" value="" name="user_email">

    <input type="hidden" value="http://xxxx/xx/xxx/paypal_cancel" name="cancel_return">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://xxx/xx/paxxypal_ipn" name="notify_url">
</form>
```

Comment: You could set the variables as session variables, submit the form with just the bare minimum of fields and then submit the data to PayPal via curl perhaps

Comment: validate form field using php, and use SSL to secure connection

Answer (score 0):

Just post to paypal via curl library and parameter CURLOPT_POST - in this case the user will not have access to change parameters

Other way is to implement PayPal Express Checkout API. There is a lot benefits to use this method instead a html form. It look more difficult than simple html form but you can save time to create IPN listener file, because response will be delivered immediately and you will not use a IPN methods to check if transaction is successful. Also you can add several recurring and one time payments in one session, including taxes and benefits. You will have the freedom to add all this stuff, practically everything.